# "android-22" can't be found in android SDK

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-sdk-tools

I'm using cocos2d-X v3.6 and I created a new cocos2d-X project and when i tried to compile, I am getting error

I have checked sdk/plarforms contained android-22 folder.

When i compile:

```
cocos compile -p android --ap android-22
```

I get this error:

The directory "android-22" can't be found in android SDK

Answer (score 0):

You have not downloaded the specified version of android. Check your Adnroid SDK folder to see what versions of android you have and then change android-22 to the version you have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not add android sdk path to system environment path called “PATH”.

suggest link: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game